# Can a company repurchase treasury stock or issue shares based on insider information?

Tags: stocks, stock-markets, insider-trading, share-repurchase

Let's say a company knows it's about to release very bad earnings, can management increase the pace of share issuance ahead of the reporting date? Likewise, if a company knows they are about to release very good earnings, can they buy back a lot of shares? On a semi-related note, are treasury stock transactions by corporations disclosed anywhere (aside from the 10k & 10q)?

Comment: I think you may have some terms mixed. Issuance or buyback changes the total shares outstanding not just the float, in other words share are being created and destroyed not just locked in a company vault. Issuance is done through the IPO process which is not a secret sudden move. Most companies have rules about any trading by insiders within a certain number of days of any announcement, as legal insurance. Moves that harm the common shareholder are grounds for direct legal action against the executives personally. (shareholder sues the executive or board member directly)

Comment: You can actually buy back shares and keep them as treasury shares.... Though I'm not quite sure if there's a benefit to it. That said, I agree with @MaxPower, you don't need treasury shares for that, you can do the same thing with regular share buybacks/issuances.